# Pandas: syslog - group by location - count unique values by day

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a Syslog wifi log I have loaded into a dataframe as follows:

```
wifi = pd.read_csv('./nov2019-wifi-stats.csv', 
                   sep='\t', 
                   parse_dates=[2],
                   header=None,
                   names=['branch','datetime','ip','mac','status'],
                   index_col=1)

wifi.head()

datetime            branch      ip              mac                 status          
Nov 1 2019 00:14:15 location1   10.100.14.101   98:b8:ba:01:as:66   sta_stats
Nov 1 2019 00:15:17 location2   10.100.14.101   98:b8:ba:01:sa:65   sta_stats
Nov 1 2019 00:27:17 location1   10.100.14.101   98:b8:ba:01:as:66   sta_stats
Nov 1 2019 00:37:54 location3   10.100.14.101   98:b8:ba:03:b8:66   sta_stats
Nov 1 2019 00:47:13 location2   10.100.14.101   98:b8:ba:01:b7:66   sta_stats
```

I need to show the monthly stats for each branch. The problem is that we calculate this by unique mac addresses per day.

The end result would:

1. Group by branch
2. Group by month
3. For each branch, count unique values in "mac" column grouped by day [ maybe this has to occur at 2 ]
4. Show totals by branch

Ex.
November stats:
Location1 2222
Location2 30303
Location3 ...
and so on.

I can group by branch but need to then get unique mac values by day then count by month for each branch.

```
wifi.groupby(['branch']).size()
```

This is more precise [ by month ] but does not look at unique mac addresses by day:

```
 wifi.index = pd.to_datetime(feet.index)
 wifi.groupby(['branch', feet.index.month]).count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is group and aggregate `nunique` along days and sum for months

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
df['month'] = df['datetime'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['datetime'].dt.day
df.groupby(['branch', 'month', 'day']).agg({'mac':'nunique'}).groupby(['branch', 'month']).agg({'mac':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

which gives you the following output

```
    month   mac
0   11      4
```

Comment: This is pretty close but doesn't group by location.

Comment: Edited my answer and added `branch` in `groupby` for location

Comment: Are you using `.month` or `.dt.month` ? use like these `df['month'] = df['datetime'].dt.month`